# Removing new files generated during SVN merge and postpone

Tags: svn, merge, conflict, merge-conflict-resolution

I have recently attempted to merge my branch with the trunk version. During the merging operation, there happened to be lot of conflicts and I had postponed them. This inturn had created lot of new files, for examples with extensions like "*.cpp.merge-left.r1048".

How can I delete these files and get back to the previous version of my branch, automatically through SVN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempted merge has copied files from both branches and attempt to merge.  Obviously, there are conflicts and these have been flagged.  These changes have not been saved to the repository, simply merged in your working directory.

These newly generated files contains the list of conflicts and possible merged file.  You can iterate through the list of conflicts using applications like Tortoise Merge which comes with Tortoise SVN.

You can try the revert command on the branch/trunk to revert back to the specific revision.
Or you can checkout the branch/trunk again.